# SSRS 2008 r2 report freezes at loading

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1. The problem is that some reports freeze at loading stage when executed in IE 11. The same reports run with no problem when we use IE9 on another workstation.

So I believe the problem has to do with IE11 compatibility. I have tried several solutions:

1. Added `<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE-Edge”>`in file `\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx` using the solution found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/)
2. Using the Report Manager, I have deactivated the timeout option for the specific report I am working on
3. I deleted the IE11 cache and browsing history

After the changes, the report worked for a few times, then started hanging again at "Loading..." stage. The execution log in the Report Server shows that data is being collected, processed and rendered with success, but no report shows up in IE

Comment: Are you sure you are using internet explorer 11 and not edge, because what are you describing seems like edge issues

Comment: yes i confirm we are using IE11